# Steam OAuth 2 Login in Vaadin Application

Tags: java, vaadin, openid, steam, steam-web-api

I tried the last 2 days to connect my vaadin application with a steam oauth to register.

But it keeps not working right.
We have security issues and a lot of other problems.

Is here someone who already did that and can explain it a bit better?

I tried literally everything and there was still a big security issue and other problems..

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @cfrick Here is the SecurityConfiguration.java: https://srcshare.io/65f4c9dce3967590e7b24872, and here is the application.properties: https://srcshare.io/65f4c9f7e3967590e7b24876, After logging into Steam, I am redirected back and greeted with the error: Error:
Could not navigate to 'login/oauth2/code/steam'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.